# How can I manage the zoom level in Google Maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want the zoom level different for different types of search. For example:- If the user searches for a `country/state/streets/buildings` the zoom level should be `5/10/15/20` respectively. How can I do this in my android app.

Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can do something like this

```
String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
   String street = addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare();
if(!knownName.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
//set zoom level 20
return;
}
if(!street .equalsIgnoreCase("")){
//set zoom level 15
return;
}
if(!state .equalsIgnoreCase("")){
//set zoom level 10
return;
}
if(!city .equalsIgnoreCase("")){
//set zoom level 5
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to set zoom base on you search results

```
map.setZoom(zoom:number)
```

Here is the refrance:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map